# PHPMailer building website for a client

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

I guess this is more of an ethics question but still technical. I'm building a website for someone and they want an email form. I've been using PHP Mailer for my personal projects but realized that I've always set `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;`.

Now that I'm building a site for someone else, I'm not sure if setting the authorization to true is good because my client may not want to give up his information. So, my question is if I set the authorization to false, will I start having problems with Gmail or any other hosts? If so, is there a way around this? A library that does not call for a password? I'm still a noob on the backend.

Comment: If you set `$mail->SMTPAuth` to `false`, then I assume it would try sending the email without authenticating first. This isn't possible with GMail; I would expect it to reject it. So, always set this to `true`. When you say your client won't want to give up their information, I presume you mean their usual email credentials. You could just use the mail system on the host, or you could create a new free account (GMail etc) just for the purposes of sending mail out from this form.

Comment: Thanks. Using another account seems simple enough.